# g++ and clang++ different behaviour for class/method variadic template types

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

Another case where g++ and clang++ behaves differently with variadic templates.

Given the following program

```
#include <utility>

template <typename ... Ks>
struct foo
 {
   template <typename ... Vs>
   foo (std::pair<Ks, Vs> ...)
    { }
 };

int main ()
 {
   foo<int>  f0{std::pair<int, char>{}};
 }
```

clang++ compile without problems where g++ gives the following error

```
tmp_004-17,gcc,clang.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
tmp_004-17,gcc,clang.cpp:28:39: error: no matching function for call to ‘foo<int>::foo(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
    foo<int>  f0{std::pair<int, char>{}};
                                       ^
tmp_004-17,gcc,clang.cpp:22:4: note: candidate: ‘template<class ... Vs> foo<Ks>::foo(std::pair<Ks, Vs>...)’
    foo (std::pair<Ks, Vs> ...)
    ^~~
tmp_004-17,gcc,clang.cpp:22:4: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
tmp_004-17,gcc,clang.cpp:28:39: note:   mismatched types ‘Vs’ and ‘char’
    foo<int>  f0{std::pair<int, char>{}};
                                       ^
tmp_004-17,gcc,clang.cpp:19:8: note: candidate: ‘constexpr foo<int>::foo(const foo<int>&)’
 struct foo
        ^~~
tmp_004-17,gcc,clang.cpp:19:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::pair<int, char>’ to ‘const foo<int>&’
tmp_004-17,gcc,clang.cpp:19:8: note: candidate: ‘constexpr foo<int>::foo(foo<int>&&)’
tmp_004-17,gcc,clang.cpp:19:8: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::pair<int, char>’ to ‘foo<int>&&’
```

Isn't completely clear but seems to me that g++ has problem mixing variadic template expansion/deduction for class/struct (`Ks...`) and methods template arguments (`Vs...`).

As usual, the question is: who's right? g++ or clang++?

Comment: It's a g++ bug. "mismatched types `Vs` and `char`" makes no sense. A workaround is to do `foo<int>  f0(std::pair<int, char>())`.

Comment: Strangely the workaround only works if there are 0 arguments to the pair constructor.

Comment: A bug without doubt. There are no initializer-list constructor and it is not a copy-intialization so overload resolution for list-initialization should be equivalent to direct initialization with parenthesis as shown by 0x4499... http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#over.match.list-1.2 and  http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.funcs#over.match.ctor-1

Comment: @0x499602D2: That’s a function declaration.

Comment: @DavisHerring Oops. Most vexing parse got me.